# How to use excel auto filter function

Tags: excel, filter

I have a big problem. I use excel auto filter function, at the end of the filter result, the next row, i need show the result summary. I know how to use excel's Formula. The problem is how can i find the row that displays the summary. Appreciating your helps. thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you autofilter an area and you want to see subtotals, or totals at the bottom, when autofiltering is taking place.

Make sure there is a blank row between what is filtered and your totals row. That way, autofilter will not hide the results. If that is what you mean